# При разбиении класса на файл h и cpp выходит ошибка LNK2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ооп

Есть класс, который надо поместить в заголовочный файл, а реализацию метода класса надо поместить в cpp файл. Но в итоге это вызывает ошибку LNK2005 "public: __thiscall Project::Project(void)" (??0Project@@QAE@XZ) уже определен в Console.obj

```
//Point.h
#pragma once

class Project
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Project();
};
```

```
//Point.cpp
#include "Point.h"

Project::Project()
{
    x = 0;

}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.cpp"
#include "Point.h"


int main()
{

    Project p;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну а где ваш Console.cpp?

Comment: Ну и на фига вы вот это сделали? `#include "Point.cpp"`? В результате вы компилируете Point.cpp дважды - один раз отдельно, один раз в составе `Console.cpp`, о чем, собственно, и сообщил вам компилятор...

Comment: Боже, как всё было просто. Спасибо всем большое!